# SciPy module names and functions fail to be defined

Tags: python, import, module, scipy, anaconda

I just installed ANACONDA and have set up my virtual environment and profile. When I enter a command like

```
from pandas import *
```

or

```
from numpy import random
```

the system pauses for a second before moving on to the next line, as expected. However, when I try to enter a command like

```
x = randn(100,100)
```

I get a message saying

> name 'randn' is not defined

Also, when I run

```
imp.find_module("pandas")
```

I get

```
(None, 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy', ('', '', 5))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your message title refers to `scipy`, but you didn't import anything from it, so I'm not sure why that's relevant.  You did two imports:

```
from pandas import *
```

which I wouldn't actually recommend; I know it's done in some tutorials, but I prefer

```
import pandas as pd
```

to keep the namespace clean.  In any case, `randn` isn't defined in the `pandas` namespace.  Then you run

```
from numpy import random
```

which only adds one new name to the namespace: `random`.  After you've done this, you can access `randn` via `random.randn`:

```
>>> from numpy import random
>>> random.randn(3)
array([-1.19504793, -0.54873061, -1.46225504])
```

If you really want to use simply `randn`, you could do

```
from numpy.random import randn
```

Comment: I always use `np.random.randn` so I don't mistake `random` for the one in the python stdlib.  `>>> import random`